# why I don't get clean data when i use cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, forms, authentication

I'm trying to create a login form for my site but when I use cleaned_data in my views.py I don't get the right data. 
here is my code: 
**views.py**

```
def login_page(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        username = form.cleaned_form.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_form.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            print("Error")
    return render(request, "auth/login.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": "Username"
            }
        )
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control",
                "placeholder": "Password"
            }
         )
    )
```

**login.html**

```
<form action="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here is what I get when I fill username and password field and click on submit. `print(form.cleaned_data)` shows there is data in url fields that I want to use but I can't access them.

[image: console]

Comment: Don't you want to write `username = form.cleaned_data[..` instead of `username = form.cleaned_form[..`, i.e. **_data** instead of **_form**?

Comment: yeah, you are right but that wasn't the real problem. I've changed some stuff in my forms.py and I forgot to correct it before I post it. the problem was using action instead of method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your view is totally wrong, use this

```
def login_page(request):
   form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
   context = {
    'form': form
   }
   if request.method == 'POST':
      if form.is_valid():
          print(form.cleaned_data)
          username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
          password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
          user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
          if user is not None:
             login(request, user)
             return redirect("/")
          else:
             print("Error")
      else:
          print('form not valid')
return render(request, "auth/login.html", context)
```

and html to

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much, the problem was using action instead of method.I checked my code more than 10 times but I didn't notice that.

Comment: Done! @Exprator

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your HTML - you should use `method="post"` instead of `action`. Right now you're sending GET at `/login/POST` with inputs as query parameters instead of POST at `/login`. This is evident in the screenshot you attached.

Valid form should look like:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```